# Why does FreezePane only work on the first sheet?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have this code that works fine, adding a FreezePane to row 7, col 3 of the first sheet (counting from the left):

```
private void FreezePane(int rowNum, int colNum)
{
    Range cellToFreeze = (Range)_xlSheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum];
    cellToFreeze.Activate();
    cellToFreeze.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
}
```

After adding another couple of sheets (the second sheet contains data as a source for a pivot table, and the third sheet contains the pivot table), I want to add a freezepane in the same place of the third/pivot Table sheet, and so I tried this:

```
private void FreezePanePivotTable(int rowToFreeze, int colToFreeze)
{
    Range pivotTableCellToFreeze = (Range)_xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[rowToFreeze, colToFreeze];
    pivotTableCellToFreeze.Activate();
    pivotTableCellToFreeze.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
}
```

That, though, crashed with "*Activate method of Range class failed Exception Source: Microsoft Office Excel
Exception StackTrace:    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(...*"

So I thought, "maybe you can only have one frozen pane in a workbook" and tried calling only the new method (leaving the first sheet unfrozen), and I get this seemingly bizarre err msg: "*Unable to set the Size property of the Font class*"

Where this exception is occurring is in the *second* sheet - the source data for sheet 3/PivotTable sheet! Why does setting the font size all of a sudden cause a problem? Line 3418 is the last line below:

```
var itemCodeLabelCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[1, 1];
itemCodeLabelCell.Value2 = "ItemCode";
itemCodeLabelCell.Style.WrapText = false;
itemCodeLabelCell.Style.Font.Size = 12;
```

Do different rules apply to adding freezepanes on the main (first) sheet and others, or is it that FreezePanes and PivotTables can't coexist, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeSheet.SomeRange.Activate()` fails if SomeSheet is not already active, hence probably the "Activate method of Range class failed".

You must activate the sheet before:

```
_xlPivotTableSheet.Activate();
pivotTableCellToFreeze.Activate();
```